# Getting iandroid.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: android

Running my chat application in android and a java server but when i run in the emulator i seem not to get a response from server.. i get:

```
android.os.DeadObjectException
```

Could anyone know what causes this exception

```
06-08 01:14:43.448 1906-1961/com.quisokey.quiso.andychat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa551d7c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-08 01:14:55.966 1906-1906/com.quisokey.quiso.andychat E/SpellCheckerSession: Failed to get suggestions android.os.DeadObjectException
06-08 01:14:57.444 1906-1906/com.quisokey.quiso.andychat E/SpellCheckerSession: Failed to get suggestions android.os.DeadObjectException
06-08 01:15:01.498 1906-1906/com.quisokey.quiso.andychat E/SpellCheckerSession: Failed to get suggestions android.os.DeadObjectException
06-08 01:15:02.902 1906-1906/com.quisokey.quiso.andychat E/SpellCheckerSession: Failed to get suggestions android.os.DeadObjectException
```

Comment: If you only want to know about DeadObjectException, then according to Android documentation, a DeadObjectException is thrown when the object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks alot thats what i needed to know